# How to group and sort object array based on string index

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, algorithm, data-structures

I want to group & re-arrange my flat array into an array of objects where each object contains its direct descendent in its children's properties.

My input Data -:

```
const data = [
  { lineNo: '1' },
  { lineNo: '1-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-3' },
  { lineNo: '1-4' },
  { lineNo: '1-11' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-3' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-4' },
  { lineNo: '1-3-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-3-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-3-3' },
  { lineNo: '1-11-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-11-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-11-3' },
  { lineNo: '2' },
  { lineNo: '2-1' },
  { lineNo: '2-2' },
  { lineNo: '2-3' },
  { lineNo: '2-2-1' },
  { lineNo: '2-2-2' },
];
```

The output I want -:

```
const newData = [
  {
    lineNo: '1',
    children: [{ lineNo: '1-1' }, { lineNo: '1-2' }, { lineNo: '1-3' }, { lineNo: '1-4' }, { lineNo: '1-11' }],
  },
  {
    lineNo: '1-2',
    children: [{ lineNo: '1-2-1' }, { lineNo: '1-2-2' }, { lineNo: '1-2-3' }, { lineNo: '1-2-4' }],
  },
  {
    lineNo: '1-3',
    children: [{ lineNo: '1-3-1' }, { lineNo: '1-3-2' }, { lineNo: '1-3-3' }],
  },
  {
    lineNo: '1-11',
    children: [{ lineNo: '1-11-1' }, { lineNo: '1-11-2' }, { lineNo: '1-11-3' }],
  },
  {
    lineNo: '2',
    children: [{ lineNo: '2-1' }, { lineNo: '2-2' }, { lineNo: '2-3' }],
  },
  {
    lineNo: '2-2',
    children: [{ lineNo: '2-2-1' }, { lineNo: '2-2-2' }],
  },
];
```

Note: The generated data must have to follow the numerical order mentioned in the output.

What i have done so far -:

```
const data = [
  { lineNo: '1' },
  { lineNo: '1-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-3' },
  { lineNo: '1-4' },
  { lineNo: '1-11' },
  { lineNo: '1-11-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-11-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-11-3' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-3' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-4' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-1-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-1-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-2-1-3' },
  { lineNo: '1-3-1' },
  { lineNo: '1-3-2' },
  { lineNo: '1-3-3' },
];

function createTree(data: any) {
  const tree: any[] = [];
  data.reduce(
    (r: any, o: any) => {
      o.lineNo
        .split('-')
        .map((_: any, i: any, a: any) => a.slice(0, i + 1).join('-'))
        .reduce((q: any, lineNo: any, i: any, { length }: any) => {
          let temp = (q.children = q.children || []).find((p: any) => p.lineNo === lineNo);
          if (!temp) {
            q.children.push((temp = { lineNo }));
          }
          if (i + 1 === length) {
            Object.assign(temp, o);
          }
          return temp;
        }, r);
      return r;
    },
    { children: tree }
  );

  return tree;
}

const createFlat = (data: any) => {
  const flat: any[] = [];
  const flatData = (data: any) => {
    data.forEach((item: any) => {
      if (item.children) {
        flat.push(item);
        flatData(item.children);
      }
    });
  };
  flatData(data);
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(flat));
};

const getCleanData = (data: any) => {
  const cleanData: any[] = [];
  function delChildren(obj: any) {
    if (obj.children) {
      obj.children.forEach((item: any) => {
        if (item.children) {
          delete item.children;
        }
      });
    }
    return obj;
  }

  data.forEach(function (item: any) {
    cleanData.push(delChildren(item));
  });

  return cleanData;
};

const treeData = createTree(data);
const flatData = createFlat(treeData);
const cleanData = getCleanData(flatData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(cleanData, null, 2));
```

I am looking for a bit simple and clean approach.

**Thank You!**

Comment: I Just added my approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first sort the data using a "natural" sort. JavaScript `localeCompare` has an option for that.

Then create a `Map` keyed by `lineNo` and with as corresponding values the objects with the same `lineNo` property and an empty `children` array property.

Then iterate the data again to populate those `children` arrays.

Extract the `Map` values and remove those objects that have an empty `children` array, *unless* they are top-level nodes (a boundary case).

Here is an implementation:

```js
function createTree(data) {
    // Apply natural ordering
    data = [...data].sort((a, b) => 
        a.lineNo.localeCompare(b.lineNo, "en", { numeric: true })
    );
    // Create key/value pairs for all lineNo in a Map
    let map = new Map(data.map(({lineNo}) => [lineNo, { lineNo, children: [] }]));
    // Populate the children arrays
    for (let {lineNo} of data) {
        map.get(lineNo.replace(/-?\d+$/, ""))?.children?.push({lineNo});
    }
    // Exclude the nodes that have no children, except if they are top-level
    return [...map.values()].filter(({lineNo, children}) => 
        !lineNo.includes("-") || children.length
    );
}

// Demo
const data = [{ lineNo: '1-1' },{ lineNo: '1-2' },{ lineNo: '1-3-2' },{ lineNo: '1-11-2' },{ lineNo: '1-3' },{ lineNo: '1-11' },{ lineNo: '1-2-3' },{ lineNo: '1-2-2' },{ lineNo: '1' },{ lineNo: '1-2-1' },{ lineNo: '1-2-4' },{ lineNo: '1-11-1' },{ lineNo: '1-3-1' },{ lineNo: '1-4' },{ lineNo: '1-3-3' },{ lineNo: '2-1' },{ lineNo: '2-2' },{ lineNo: '2-2-1' },{ lineNo: '1-11-3' },{ lineNo: '2' },{ lineNo: '2-3' },{ lineNo: '2-2-2' },];

console.log(createTree(data));
```